# Gibt es eine Regel für das Genus von denglischen Substantiven?

Tags: gender

Beispiel: PGP-Key

Intuitiv würde ich sagen "der PGP-Key", weil "der Schlüssel". Ich habe aber letztens "das Key" gelesen.

Was ist richtig?